# Same height for images in Bootstrap 3 columns (Material Kit Pro UI)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, height, responsive

So I've started using Material Kit UI and right now as you can see in the picture the image inside columns are different in height.
[image]

and also here is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid sec1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <div class="anime card card-blog">
                <div class="card-image animeimg">
                    <div class="timenumber">
                        <h4>2 دقیقه قبل</h4>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" title="Sword Art Online">
                        <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki247.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="colored-shadow" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki247.jpg&quot;); opacity: 1;"></div>
                    <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="card-content sectit">
                    <h6 class="category text-success">در حال پخش</h6>
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        <a href="#" title="Sword Art Online">Sword Art Online</a>
                    </h4>

                    <div class="footer episodenumber">
                        قسمت 13
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
    .anime {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
.card-blog {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.card {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.87);
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.card .card-image {
    height: 60%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.animeimg {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.timenumber {
    z-index: 9999;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.card .card-image img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.card .card-image .colored-shadow {
    transform: scale(0.94);
    top: 12px;
    filter: blur(12px);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity .45s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.ripple-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: inherit;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.animeimg:after {
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 98.5%;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: "";
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
}
.card .card-content {
    padding: 15px 30px;
}
.sectit {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.sectit > h6 {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
}
.text-success {
    color: #4caf50;
}
.text-success {
    color: #3c763d;
}
.card-blog .card-title {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.sectit > h4 {
    width: 60%;
}
.sectit > h4 {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 65%;
    direction: ltr;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: .9rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.title, .title a, .card-title, .card-title a, .info-title, .info-title a, .footer-brand, .footer-brand a, .footer-big h5, .footer-big h5 a, .footer-big h4, .footer-big h4 a, .media .media-heading, .media .media-heading a {
    color: #3C4858;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.title, .card-title, .info-title, .footer-brand, .footer-big h5, .footer-big h4, .media .media-heading {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", "Times New Roman", serif;
}
.sectit > h4 > a {
    color: #000;
}
.title, .title a, .card-title, .card-title a, .info-title, .info-title a, .footer-brand, .footer-brand a, .footer-big h5, .footer-big h5 a, .footer-big h4, .footer-big h4 a, .media .media-heading, .media .media-heading a {
    color: #3C4858;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.card .footer {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.episodenumber {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 8px !important;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

so I've tried to change height in ".card img" (from auto to 18rem) but the images wasn't responsive anymore.
I also tried to set min-height but it didn't work too.

here two image with different height: 
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki247.jpg 
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGjYd.jpg

Comment: because your all images are not of same dimension...

Comment: @Bhuwan but as you can see (for example masterani.me) there're lot of websites using images with different dimension. also if you try the code and change height in ".card img" from auto to something you will see what I mean.

Comment: they are using `position:absolute` in the image...you will need to set the height of `a` tag and `overflow:hidden`....also put absolute path of the images in your question to solve the issue....

Comment: @Bhuwan It didn't work... (or maybe I didn't do it in a right way) could please give me the exact code?

Comment: first paste the absolute path for the images in your question...not the local path...

Comment: @Bhuwan I've uploaded two image with different height. and I've added their link at the end of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need set the height of `.card .card-image a` and then `overflow:hidden` to hide the extra content.

```
.card .card-image a {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.anime {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.card-blog {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.card .card-image {
  height: 60%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.animeimg {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.timenumber {
  z-index: 9999;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.card .card-image img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.card .card-image .colored-shadow {
  transform: scale(0.94);
  top: 12px;
  filter: blur(12px);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity .45s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.ripple-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.animeimg:after {
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 98.5%;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
}

.card .card-content {
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

.sectit {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.sectit>h6 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: none;
}

.text-success {
  color: #4caf50;
}

.text-success {
  color: #3c763d;
}

.card-blog .card-title {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) .sectit>h4 {
  width: 60%;
}

.sectit>h4 {
  margin-top: 5px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 65%;
  direction: ltr;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.title,
.title a,
.card-title,
.card-title a,
.info-title,
.info-title a,
.footer-brand,
.footer-brand a,
.footer-big h5,
.footer-big h5 a,
.footer-big h4,
.footer-big h4 a,
.media .media-heading,
.media .media-heading a {
  color: #3C4858;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title,
.card-title,
.info-title,
.footer-brand,
.footer-big h5,
.footer-big h4,
.media .media-heading {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", "Times New Roman", serif;
}

.sectit>h4>a {
  color: #000;
}

.title,
.title a,
.card-title,
.card-title a,
.info-title,
.info-title a,
.footer-brand,
.footer-brand a,
.footer-big h5,
.footer-big h5 a,
.footer-big h4,
.footer-big h4 a,
.media .media-heading,
.media .media-heading a {
  color: #3C4858;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card .footer {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.episodenumber {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px !important;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.card .card-image a {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid sec1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="anime card card-blog">
        <div class="card-image animeimg">
          <div class="timenumber">
            <h4>2 دقیقه قبل</h4>
          </div>
          <a href="#" title="Sword Art Online">
            <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki247.jpg">
          </a>
          <div class="colored-shadow" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki247.jpg&quot); opacity: 1;"></div>
          <div class="ripple-container"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-content sectit">
          <h6 class="category text-success">در حال پخش</h6>
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#" title="Sword Art Online">Sword Art Online</a>
          </h4>

          <div class="footer episodenumber">
            قسمت 13
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="anime card card-blog">
        <div class="card-image animeimg">
          <div class="timenumber">
            <h4>2 دقیقه قبل</h4>
          </div>
          <a href="#" title="Sword Art Online">
            <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGjYd.jpg">
          </a>
          <div class="colored-shadow" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGjYd.jpg&quot;); opacity: 1;"></div>
          <div class="ripple-container"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-content sectit">
          <h6 class="category text-success">در حال پخش</h6>
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#" title="Sword Art Online">Sword Art Online</a>
          </h4>

          <div class="footer episodenumber">
            قسمت 13
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Artimos what is getting same after deleting `.animeimg:after` and also you will need to set the height of `<a>` according to your screen size using media queries